# Equality of vectors in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, equality

I was trying to solve this problem

- https://www.4clojure.com/problem/32

and I realized that this statement gave output as false.

```clj
(= (#(into [] (distinct %)) [1 2 3]) 
   '(1 1 2 2 3 3))
```

It is supposed to be true as the function is also returning the same vector.

Can someone please explain to me why this is false?

Comment: You are using `distinct` against `[1 2 3]` not on `'(1 1 2 2 3 3)`

Comment: The problem is asking you to write a function that duplicates each element of the sequence. `distinct` works in the opposite direction, _removing_ duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I found out that I was using the distinct method incorrectly and hence decided to use the repeat method to get the answer which was:

```
mapcat #(repeat 2 %)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question you ask is irrelevant to the problem you refer to, which [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65377942/1562315) solves. Looking at the question alone ...

- As rascio comments, you are applying `distinct` to the wrong
  sequence.
- Furthermore, you can apply `=` to any two sequences. You don't have
  to convert the lazy sequence that `distinct` produces to a vector.

Thus the following suffices ...

```
(= [1 2 3] (distinct '(1 1 2 2 3 3)))
=> true
```